# How to pass Stellargraph as an input to Keras model?

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer, stellargraph

I am unable to pass Stellargraph graph as an input to Keras model using Input().
It gives an error:
Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'stellargraph.core.graph.StellarGraph'>, <class 'NoneType'>
Is there a way to define input passing a stellargraph object?

Comment: You need to convert this to a floating point vector, not just pass a whole unknown object.

Comment: Can you explain further how to do this?